# custom count in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array with strings as follows:

```
Tim Jones
Karl Smith
Tim Jones
T Jones
K Smith
Tim JONES
```

I want to obtain the count of the number of occurrences of each of the string in the array. I used `array_count_values`. But it returns

```
Tim Jones : 2
Karl Smith : 1
T Jones : 1
K Smith : 1
Tim JONES : 1
```

But I need to check only the last names and the **first letter of the first name also** for counting

```
Tim Jones : 4
Karl Smith : 2
```

Any suggestions as to how to do this. Thanks

**Edit**

This is a more correct example. If the array is

```
Tim Jones
Karl Smith
Harry Jones
Tim Jones
T Jones
K Smith
Tim JONES
```

The output should be

```
Tim Jones : 4
Karl Smith : 2
Harry Jones : 1
```

I am not so familiar with PHP. I came across `array_count_values` and tried it. But I need to do some array splitting and searching and counting.

Based on Chris code, this is what I have now

```
<?php
$names = array (
'Tim Jones',
'Karl Smith',
'Tim Jones',
'T Jones',
'K Smith',
'Tim JONES'
);

$counts = array();
$actualMap = array();

foreach ($names as $name) {
$last_name = strtolower(array_pop((explode(' ', $name))));
$first_name_letter = substr(strtolower(array_shift((explode(' ', $name)))), 0, 1);

$first_name = array_shift(explode(' ',$name));
$actualKey = $first_name . ' '. ucfirst($last_name);

$key = $first_name_letter . ' '. $last_name;

if (array_key_exists($key, $counts) === false){
    $counts[$key] = 0;
    $actualMap[$key] = $actualKey;
}

$counts[$key]++;
}
print_r($counts);
print_r($actualMap);

?>
```

I obtain the following

```
 Array ( [t jones] => 4 [k smith] => 2 ) Array ( [t jones] => Tim Jones [k smith] => Karl Smith )
```

I need to replace the keys now

Comment: Make an array of last names, and call `array_count_values` on that.

Comment: show us what you have done so far and you need to search last name so, you will need last names as an array then use http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/E4kFgR

Comment: @Barmar I updated the question to the correct one. Please see my edit.

Comment: Make an array of `first-initial last-name` and call `array_count_values` on that.

Comment: With edited requirements: http://codepad.viper-7.com/XpfOzZ -- pretty basic stuff man.

Comment: Tim, Tom, Terry, and Theodore Jones won't appreciate your solution, but that's one way to skin a cat. Don't even mention it to Joe, Jim, John, Jerry, or Jeremiah Smith though.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the solution but I need the full first name in the result array. So should I store some mapping for it?

Comment: @Chris Could you post your solution as answer..

Answer (score 0):

1) 
Run through the list creating a `[(First letter + " " +unique last name, count=0) , ...]` list as you go.

Or

You can use array_unique. [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) is the documentation

2)
Then run through the list again comparing to the first list and add to a count for that unique last name.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this is what you are asking for but I would normalize the names in the array and then you can count them

```
$array=array("Tim Jones","Karl Smith","Tim Jones","T Jones","K Smith","Tim JONES");

function editArray($array){
foreach($array as $x){
    list($firstname,$notfirst)=explode(" ",$x);
    $newnames[]=strtolower($firstname[0]." ".$notfirst);
}
return $newnames;
}
$newarray=editArray($array);
print_r(array_count_values($newarray));
```